# Is there a snapchat client for WindowsPhone?

Tags: apps

There is no official Snapchat client I am aware of, but is there an unofficial one - do Snapchat provide APIs that make this possible (as for instance SoundCloud do)?

Comment: Be advised that using unofficial Snapchat apps can get your account banned from the service completely.

Answer (score 2):

There is this app [Specter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/specter/9nblggh5kldb) which still works! According to WM Poweruser in this [article](http://mspoweruser.com/heres-how-to-use-snapchat-on-your-windows-phone/),

> as of March 2016 the only currently working Snapchat app on Windows
>   Phone is Specter.

The app is highly basic and still in beta. But windows phone users have no other option as there is no official app and all 3rd party apps were closed by Snapchat<sup>[Ref -1](https://www.windowscentral.com/6snap-removed-store-along-all-third-party-snapchat-windows-phone-apps)</sup>.

There is no hope for advanced features as

1. Snapchat indicated it will not make a windows phone version
2. It removed all 3rd party apps
3. The removed the feature request option which allowed asking support windows phones.
4. Snapchat CEO tweeted as follows about Windows phone,
   [image]
   Image source [Windows Central article](https://www.windowscentral.com/snapchats-lawyers-send-threatening-letter-6discover)
5. Snapchat's lawyers send threatening letter to Huyn over new 6discover app

**References** :

1. [Here’s how to use Snapchat on your Windows Phone - WMPoweruser](http://mspoweruser.com/heres-how-to-use-snapchat-on-your-windows-phone/)
2. [6snap removed from store, along with all third-party Snapchat Windows Phone apps - Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/6snap-removed-store-along-all-third-party-snapchat-windows-phone-apps)
3. [Snapchat silences critics, removes support form - Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/snapchat-silences-critics-removes-support-form)
4. [How you can't get Snapchat on Windows Phone: The whole sorry saga - WindowsCentral](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-you-cant-get-snapchat-windows-phone-whole-sorry-saga)
5. [Snapchat's lawyers send threatening letter to Huyn over new 6discover app - Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/snapchats-lawyers-send-threatening-letter-6discover)

Comment: Seems I have to already have an account... which I can only sign up for through the iOS/Android app?!

Comment: @Mr.Boy It is beacuse Snapchat does not care about WP. Hope my updated answer can explain you why I say that.